# extract xlsx file with phpspreadsheet doesn't work

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I have a specific xlsx file auto-generated by a sport performance monitoring tool.

[An example of this file](http://bruet.iiens.net/Excel/ExtractExcelProblem.xlsx)

To extract data on my file, I use the [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) class.

This is my code :

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($this->filePath);

$spreadsheet = $reader->load($this->filePath);
$value = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();
var_dump($value);
```

Normaly this code should give output of 2 names in the sheet : ['Données', 'Résultats']

But the code output : `array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Worksheet" }`

It's an empty file.

The weird thing is if I open the file with Excel Program and I save the file without making no modifications, my code output the right sheet names..

**Has anyone encountered this problem ?**

Comment: are you 100% sure the filepath is correct?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure ! Because if I open the file with Excel and then I saved it with Excel, my code works perfectly..

Comment: It's weird, it's like the file was wrong formatted... But I could open this file with Excel and with GoogleSheet

Comment: how do you create the file?

Comment: I don't create the file. It's autogenerate by sport performance monitoring device

Comment: I believe this problem is caused by namespaces being added to the Excel file by the program that creates it. It's a known issue. If you open and save the file with Excel then try loading it again, it should work.